# How do I get the id of a newly created resource in a Joosy.Form.attach callback?

Tags: joosy

I have the following in my joosy page:

```
@afterLoad ->
  @form = Joosy.Form.attach @rawForm,
    resource: @data.presentation
    success: (data) => 
      @navigate '/presentations'
```

But instead of navigating to `/presentations`, I want to navigate to the newly created presentation. How can I get the id for the newly created object? It doesn't appear to be in the `data` param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newly created id *will* be in the `data` parameter as long as it's returned in the json for the resource being created. In my case, I needed to edit the default `app/views/presentations/show.json.jbuilder` to add the `:id` field.